# ¿Porque el método setSize no necesita de un objeto , a diferencia que la mayoría de los métodos?

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

¿Porque el método `setSize` no necesita de un objeto , a diferencia que la mayoría de los métodos?
ejemplo:

```
class MarcoConDibujos extends JFrame{
    public MarcoConDibujos(){ // constructor
        setTitle("prueba de dibujo");  
        setSize(400,400);   // ¿porque estos métodos no necesitan objetos?
    }
}
```

Diferente a otro método donde si que usa un objeto.

ejemplo:

```
Timer miTemporizador = new Timer(intervalo, oyente);

    miTemporizador.start();
```

Comment: Hola Erick, bienvenido a SOes, te aconsejo que completes el [tour] para conseguir tu primera *medalla* y aprender más cosas sobre el SOes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código es equivalente al siguiente:

```
class MarcoConDibujos extends JFrame{

    public MarcoConDibujos(){ // constructor
        this.setTitle("prueba de dibujo");  
        this.setSize(400,400);
    }
}
```

Cuando dentro de un objeto te quieres referir a él mismo, puedes usar `this`. En la mayoría de los casos su uso es **opcional**, sólo es obligatorio cuando puede haber conflictos, como

```
class Prueba {
    String dato;
    void setDato(String dato) {
        this.dato = dato; //this.dato es el atributo, dato es el parámetro
    }
}
```

O cuando quieres hacer referencia al objeto en su totalidad, como en este ejemplo:

```
class A {

    String dato1, dato2;

    A setDato1 (String d) {
       dato1 = d;
       return this;
    }

    A setDato2 (String d) {
       dato2 = d;
       return this;
    }

    public static void main (String ...args) {
        // se instancia un A y se le asigna valores a sus atributos de 
        // manera encadenada
        A obj= new A().setDato1("Hola").setDato("Mundo");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bueno respecto a tu pregunta, el JFrame es una clase en la cual tiene diferentes métodos proveídos por la librería de Java Swing, ¿Por qué estos métodos no necesitan objetos? La respuesta es simple por que así se los ha proveído la librería. La clase Window tiene estos métodos que por herencia es compartido al JFrame, el método [setSize(int width, int height)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setSize(int,%20int)) en la cual le pasas como parámetros el ancho y la altura. También puedes usar el método [setSize(Dimension dimension)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setSize(java.awt.Dimension)) donde aquí si le pasas un object dimension el cual también tiene el ancho y altura.

Comment: Se refiere a que delante del método no hay un objeto al cual pertenezca: `obj.metodo()` y (this.)`metodo()`

Comment: Ok xD entendí mal xD hehe pero igual ahí está alguna referencia que le podría ayudar a alguien :)